# Swift: How to shrink an image down to thumbnail size (without losing quality?)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to take images in an array and shrink them down to thumbnail size. I have in mind the way an image looks when you assign someone a picture in contacts and the little picture comes up next to their name in texts. The method I'm using now creates an extremely blurry image - is there anything I can change to make it look like the quality in contacts?

```
var newSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
pic.drawInRect(rect)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pass `0.0`, not `1.0` as the last argument to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

Comment: And using PNG instead of JPG since PNG is lossless.

Comment: thats like asking to shrink a novel down to a sentence without losing any key parts of the storyline